# Pure CSS table of contents

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, css-counter

I am building a webpage that prints to a PDF, and each "page" (a 210x297mm div) has automatic page numbers generated using CSS counters, like so:

```css
  .pageNumber::before {
    content: counter(page, decimal-leading-zero);
    color: $medium-grey-color;
    font-size: 8pt;
  }
```

Now, I need to build a table of contents and I'm wondering if it can be done using pure CSS.

Structure:

```
[ 
  TOC page
  Section 1 .... Page 41
  Section 2 .... Page 45
                          ]

[ Page 41
  Section 1
  -- content -- ]

[ Page 45
  Section 2
  -- content -- ]
```

Let's say the numbers "Page 41" and "Page 45" are already displayed properly in the content pages, but how do I copy those automatically generated page numbers to the Table of Contents using CSS only, or something in React?

The number of pages in the document is not fixed.